# Mark each row as successful after running google script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have written a script that sends emails using a google sheet. Everything works properly, except marking the third column as successful. The first successful email is marked EMAIL_SENT, but none of the following cells are changed. Any ideas why this doesn't work?

```
for (row = 1; row < emailLength && confirmation == ui.Button.YES; row++){

  var customerEmail = data[row][0]; // Customer's email in first column

  var customerName = data[row][1]; // Customer's name in second column

  var EMAIL_SENT = 'Success';

  if(customerName != ''){

      var body = '<font face="avenir" size="3"> Hi '+ customerName + ',<br><br>' 
      + paragraphOne + '<br><br>'
      + paragraphTwo + '<br><br>'
      + paragraphThree + '<br><br>'
      + signature;
    }


  GmailApp.sendEmail(customerEmail, emailSubject, "", {htmlBody: body});

  sheet.getRange(row, 3).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
}
};
```

Comment: I cannot be sure with the code you've shared, but my first try would be that sheet object is out of scope. Do you get any error on javascript console when you execute your code?

Comment: There appears to be a mismatch between row indices. row = 1 is the first row of the sheet. But data[1][0] refers to the 2nd row of the data you process, since the JavaScript index begins with 0.

Comment: @sandwich that is intentional since there are headers. Good thought though!

Comment: @Bardo no errors. It sends all the emails but doesn't mark them as successful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@bardo was on the right track. The issue was with getRange. With the way the code was originally, getRange(row, 3) was starting off on the third column and the first row. I wanted it to start off on the second row. data[row][x] was fine because those are indexes, but getRange needed to be `getRange(row + 1 , 3)`

```
  sheet.getRange(row + 1, 3).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
```